# How to tell if a flag in already defined in a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

I have a `makefile` in which I want to include a specific `src` file conditionally. The `makefile` is looks like:

```
###############################################
# Load default top-level config
include $(WORKROOT)/build/linux/config.mk

ifndef START_TIME
  export START_TIME:="$(shell date +%s)"
endif

#include $(MAK_DIR)/source.inc
include $(WORKROOT)/build/linux/source.inc
```

in `config.mk` it's like:

```
export FLAGS = \
-DFLAGA \
-DFLAGB
```

in `source.inc` I want to:

```
#IF FLAGA is defined in FLAGS in config.mk THEN:
my-objs += \
$(WORKROOT)/My_DIR/specific_src.cpp
#ENDIF
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the literal string `-DFLAGA` in the `FLAGS` variable then you can use the [`$(filter)` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-filter).

```
ifneq (,$(filter -DFLAGA,$(FLAGS)))
my-objs += \
$(WORKROOT)/My_DIR/specific_src.cpp
endif
```